# rails MailForm doesn't go through validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-form

I can't get the validation to work:

My Contact.rb Model:

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base


    attribute :name  
    attribute :e_mail    
    attribute :message

  validates_presence_of :name 
  validates_format_of :e_mail, :with =>  /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  validates_presence_of :message

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Kontaktu forma",
      :to => "myemail@domain.lv",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{e_mail}>)
    }
  end
end
```

contacts_controller.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js
     def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact]).deliver
  end
end
```

new.js :

```
$("#main-block").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'contact_form') %>")
```

_contact_form.html.erb:

```
  <%= form_for :contact, :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :name, class: "control-label" %>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :e_mail, class: "control-label" %>
          <%= f.email_field :e_mail %>

        <%= f.label :message, class: "control-label" %>
          <%= f.text_area :message %>
      </br>
            <%= f.submit('Send', class: "btn btn-primary")  %>
  <% end %>
```

create.js:

```
 <%= render 'save' %>
```

_save.js.erb:

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @mail.errors.any? %>
  <% @mail.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  $("#main-block").empty()
  $("#main-block").html("Ziņa ir nosūtīta. Tuvākajā laikā sniegsim atbildi!")
<% end %>
```

Before I had error for not having .errors method but somehow I fixed that and now it bypasses all validations and simply Accepts the POST request of my save.js.erb

EDIT: Weirdly everything seems to be workinng just fine through console.

EDIT 2: Tried changing the form_for from :contact to @contact, now I get the undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass method in _save.js.erb

Comment: Could you add the `new.html.erb` to your code samples?

Comment: I don't have a new.html since it uses AJAX request when going to the contact_us page. This is why I have new.js and then partial form to render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `nilClass` issue is probably because the `deliver` method does not return a `Contact`.  And I don't see anywhere where you are calling the validation methods.
 Most AR objects call validations on `valid?` or `save`.  Since you're not explicitly saving anything here, I'm not sure when the validation is expected to happen.  But you could be explicit about it... like

```
@contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
@contact.deliver if @contact.valid?
```

This should solve the `nilClass` issue that you were having which was probably because now `@contact` is a real `Contact object.  Also, you're explicitly calling the validation methods.

Comment: Awesome. This helped. They should probably add this in MailForm gem  description since for a beginner like me the validation through explicit methods like valid? or save is news.

Comment: That validation pattern is set for `ActiveRecord`.  Since this is a `gem`, it's not surprising that it's a little different, but you're right.  It wouldn't hurt to have a little note in the [mail_form gem's](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form) docs.  You could file an issue on their [github issue tracker](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form/issues) and they might fix that up in the future.